# Why does the JVM slow down over time only when using the CMS garbage collector?

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm, nashorn

I have an application that uses Nashorn. For the purposes of my example, I create a ScriptContext that I prepare by executing some Javascript to create some globals, and then use that context over and over again in a single thread by calling `NashornScriptEngine#eval(String, ScriptContext)` in a tight loop. I do not store the result anywhere and as far as I can tell my application code does not cause any side effects.

With the default GC this works fine indefinitely. But when I run the same application with `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` performance significantly degrades over time. When the program starts, it takes about 2 minutes to run 1,000,000 iterations. But after 2 hours, the same 1,000,000 iterations takes about 4 minutes. It continues to get worse from there.

I've also tested regularly throwing away the NashornScriptEngine instance along with the ScriptContext, starting over entirely. At that point, my application has no reference to any variable from the previous execution. That does not improve these performance issues.

Any idea what's going on? I need to run with `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` because this is just a small piece of a larger long lived application.

I have some screenshots from Java Mission Control below (taken from Flight Recorder).

Thanks!

[image: Heap]
[image: Reference Objects]
[image: Top Growers]

Here I've picked two GCs, one from the beginning of the recording, one from the end. Note how "JNI Weak Reference" time increases significantly, as does "GC Pause".

[image: GC At Beginning]
[image: GC At End]

Comment: If this is a CMS-only issue, have you tried G1? Also, which java version? I think CMS only started to do class unloading by default with java8.

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8177098.
Could you try workaround - recreate NashornScriptEngineFactory each time?

Comment: I did try recreating the NashornScriptEngineFactory every 1,000,000 iterations (2 minutes), but that didn't appear to help. I have to wonder if the workaround in that bug just happened to slow it down enough that he didn't see the issue (because creating the engine is so much more expensive than just `eval()`ing).

Comment: @swqnzd (*Just guessing*) Maybe related to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8176454? If the GC does not really work, then dropping the factory can't help. If it was a problem with some statics, then it could be solved using a separate class loader, but with native memory nothing but a new process can help (if you don't communicate much data, then creating new processes could be worth a try).

Answer (score 0):

As you noted yourself it spends a lot of time in JNI ref processing. This is single-threaded by default. Set `-XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled` to let it run in parallel.

Since you're using the nashorn engine which dynamically generates bytecode it might also be an issue with class unloading or lack thereof, but that is not evident from your logs.

Comment: Looking at Mission Control, loaded classes stays pretty flat, so I don't think that's the issue. I'll give `-XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled` a try.

Comment: ParallelRefProcEnabled seems to have decreased the amount of time, but the issue is clearly still there - increasing from 1ms per GC at the beginning to 70ms per GC after an hour.